# Prevent load of initial data of the broadleaf heat clinic shop

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

How can i prevent the demo site to load the catalog of the heat clinic demo?

all i need is an empty shop with admin roles and permissions, no catalog data, no translations.

Answer (score 0):

This is configured with a property, `import.sql.enabled`. If you set this to false then no data will be loaded at all.

To include or exclude specific import SQL, we do not have a great way to manage that piece by piece yet. Specifically for admin roles/permissions you would need [this import](https://github.com/BroadleafCommerce/BroadleafCommerce/blob/develop-5.2.x/core/broadleaf-framework/src/main/java/org/broadleafcommerce/core/demo/ImportSQLConfig.java#L43) to execute, which would be as easy as moving this `@Bean` method inside of your own `@Configuration` classes in your project (like `CorePersisteceConfig`).